# KENDO MVC GRID / Arithmetic operation in ClientTemplate

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm the beginner and using c#, asp.net mvc, kendo mvc.

I wanna +, - operation in kendo grid clientTemplate

**it works :**

```
.ClientTemplate("#: DRE_06 == 0 ? 0 : kendo.toString(DRE_05/DRE_06, '\\#\\#,\\#') #")
```

**it doesn't work :**

```
.ClientTemplate("#=kendo.toString(F_PI-F_PS, 'n0')) #")
```

how do i using it for +, - operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

```
.ClientTemplate("#=kendo.toString(F_PI-F_PS, 'n0')) #")
```

Make sur the variables F_PI and F_PS are defined.

I tried using the following code and it works:

```
.ClientTemplate("# var F_PI = 6; var F_PS = 3 # #= kendo.toString(F_PI-F_PS, 'n0') #") // output: 3
```